# Dynamically import a module in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a base react application which has to embed other react applications dynamically. For eg

App1 (Base app)
--> App2 (child app1)
--> App3 (child app2)

App2 and App3 are independently built react applications.
I need a way to dynamically importing these apps into App1.
One way I did was, added the built js and CSS files into respective folders in node-modules(refer to the link for file structure)

[image]

I am trying to import the app2 and app3 dynamically in App1,

```
let path = `../../node-modules/${application.title}/build/${application.title}`
    let pathCss = `../../node-modules/${application.title}/build/${application.title}.css`
    import('' + pathCss)
    .then(component =>
    console.log('css file loaded', component)
    ).catch(error => {
    console.error(`"${application.title}" not yet supported ${error}`);
    });
        
    import('' + path)
    .then(component =>
    this.setState({
    routeComponents: this.state.routeComponents.concat(component.App)
    })
    )
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(`"${application.title}" not yet supported ${error}`);
    });
```

but this does not seem to find the applications and gives the error that it cannot load modules outside the src folder.
Any suggestions on how this can be achieved?

Comment: Does this work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58931464/11380693 ?

Comment: Publishing is fine, we can publish a repo to the repository.However, dynamic loading does not work .I am trying to dynamically load the components in my componentDidMount. Here it is not allowing to refer to anything outside the src folder

Comment: The reason you can't refer anything outside src folder is because it is a special restriction of create-react-app. It is implemented in ModuleScopePlugin to ensure files reside in src folder

Comment: Is there any other way to dynamically import modules which are packaged in node-modules?

Answer (score 3):

take a look at this solution https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-elgamal-l6po2

You can see the `Loading` component been rendered while the `App1` component is being fetched.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function Loading() {
  return <div>Loading</div>;
}

export default function App() {
  const [comp, setComp] = useState(Loading);

  useEffect(() => {
    const load = async () => {
      const App1 = (await import("./App1")).default;
      setComp(App1);
    };

    load();
  }, []);

  return <>{comp}</>;
}
```